# Assign Value To Variable After Extracting From Json File Using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

I have the below json file

```
{
    "name": "ca",
    "version": "5.2.0"
}
```

I am extracting the value of version and trying to assign it to a variable ver

```
$jsonString = Get-Content -Path ./package.json
$jsonObj = $jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json

echo $jsonObj.version

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ver]$jsonObj.version"

echo $ver
```

Below is the output

```
5.2.0
```

I am expecting the value to be printed twice and also get it assigned to the variable ver but it is not getting assigned

Comment: Nope, in PowerShell, you've assigned it once and printing it once. You haven't provided detail as to what you're trying to do, i.e. what is the `vso` stuff?

Comment: @codaamok I am trying to assign it to a variable so that I can use it in the output of the azure devops pipeline. So, I got vso from Microsoft Documents of Azure Devops Pipeline

Comment: Yeah, sounds like that's not the same as a PowerShell variable. Perhaps a variable in the ADO engine/runner instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use it in builds, you will not see a new value in the same step. Additionally, use `$($jsonObj.version)` in the logging command:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   
   $jsonString = Get-Content -Path ./package.json
   $jsonObj = $jsonString | ConvertFrom-Json
   
   $jsonObj.version
   
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=my.ver]$($jsonObj.version)"

  displayName: 'Set vars'

- powershell: |
   $ver = '$(my.ver)'
   
   $ver
   
  displayName: 'Read vars'
```

Comment: Is it possible to set `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VAR]$($jsonObj)"` and in second task get nested value `'$(VAR.version)'` ?

Comment: @itiic I do not think so. However, you can try to convert your object to json-string without new lines (like, `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`). Then in the next steps convert it to an object.

Comment: Yes, minified JSON is being passed. 
Example: 
`task1:
  $minifyJSON  = Get-Content 'variables.json' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VARS;]$minifyJSON"
  
task2:
  $V =  '$(VARS)' | ConvertFrom-Json
  Write-Host "$($V.key.key_nested)"
`